# Add custom text around a barcode with Zend_Pdf (Zend Framework 1.12)

Tags: zend-framework, barcode

I want to add a custom text around a barcode inside a PDF-document using Zend_Pdf and Zend_Barcode. Right now it is only showing the barcode but I want to add my custom text too above it.

So now I am getting this: [image]

but I want this: [image]

Here is my code:

```
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
        $hidden =$_POST['hidden']; 
        $quantityfrom =$_POST['quantity_from']; 
        $quantityto =$_POST['quantity_to']; 
        //Here is code for update the Quantity
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $table = new Account_Model_DbTable_Products();
        $query = $table->updateQuantity($product_id,$quantityto);


        Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont(dirname(ROOT_PATH) .  '/inventory/library/Zend/Barcode/Object/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf'); 

        $numberOfPages = ceil(($quantityto-$quantityfrom)/15);
        $equipmentCount = $quantityto-$quantityfrom+1;

        for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPages; $i++)
        {
          $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
          $width  = $page->getWidth();        // A4 : 595
          $height = $page->getHeight();       // A4 : 842
          $page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);
          $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        }
          $index = 0;
          for($j=1 ; $j<=$numberOfPages;$j++){

            if($equipmentCount > 10)
          {
            $barcodesOnThisPage = 10;
            $equipmentCount = $equipmentCount - 10;
          }
          else
          {
            $barcodesOnThisPage = $equipmentCount;
          } 
          echo $barcodesOnThisPage."</br>";
                $k = 1;
            for($i=1;$i<=$barcodesOnThisPage;$i++){

                $num_padded = sprintf("%04d", $quantityfrom);
                $barcodeOptions = array(
                    'text' => $hidden.$num_padded,
                     'barHeight' =>100,
                     );
                $rendererOptions = array(
                'topOffset' => 80*$k,
                'horizontalPosition' =>'left'   
                );

                $pdfWithBarcode = Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf', 
                $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf,$index)->draw();

                $pdfWithBarcode->save('testBarcode.pdf'); 
                $k++;
                $quantityfrom++;
               }
               $index++;
               }
          $this->_redirect('/testBarcode.pdf');
     }
```

Comment: Great ... And the question is?

Comment: Please check i updated my question above.

Comment: You'll need to add the additional text and the vector to your PDF-generator. It's a little bit hard to answer because I don't know what library you are using to generate the barcode (Zend\Barcode I guess) and to generate the PDF.

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to generate the barcode and pdf. This will help us work out what the issue is and offer suggestions :)

Comment: I updated my code above.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html

Comment: thanks for your feedback but above link is used to draw text on pdf page, but i want print my text with barcode till end of loop.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: yes @prinzechristian

Comment: Can you post it as an answer? @Deepaksaini

Comment: sorry, actually I used barcode api, I have a number that I want to convert into barcode, I requested to barcode api with that number and it returned me an image then with the help of css I found it.
example:-
echo '<img src="http://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?code=Code39&modulewidth=fit&data=7410852012&dpi=96&imagetype=gif&rotation=0&color=&bgcolor=&fontcolor=&quiet=0&qunit=mm&download=true"/>';